# How to serialize Manatee.Json.JsonValue?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, manatee.json

I use `Manatee.Json.JsonValue` a whole lot, for instance in a case I have now, where I have a property of type `object`. This `object` property can contain both literals or complex types.

When the property value contains a complex type of `JsonValue`, it is serialized as an empty object! Is it possible to avoid this, such that other property values are serialized, while `object` property values of type `JsonValue` are just copied?

Here is an example with `Manatee.Json.13.0.2`:

```cs
public class TestObject
{
    public object Property { get; set; }
}

[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        var testObject = new TestObject
        {
            Property = new JsonValue("testString")
        };

        JsonValue expected = new JsonValue(
            new JsonObject
            {
                ["Property"] = "testString",
            }
        );

        var serializer = new Manatee.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializer();
        JsonValue actual = serializer.Serialize(testObject);

        var expectedString = expected.ToString();
        /// expectedString  "{\"Property\":\"testString\"}" string

        var actualString = actual.ToString();
        /// actualString    "{\"Property\":{}}" string

        Assert.AreNotEqual(expectedString, actualString);
    }
}
```

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

So, I've come to find a solution that seems to cover my use case.
I have managed to create a simple `JsonSerializer` that copies values. Upon serialization, the goal is to go from the source object to a `JsonValue` target. If the source value is either a `JsonValue`, a `JsonObject` or a `JsonArray` instance, the serialization method returns a `JsonValue`. Other types throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Upon deserialization, the goal is to go from a `JsonValue` and back to the requested type. If the requested type is a `JsonValue`, the current `JsonValue` are returned. If the requested type is a `JsonObject`, either the current `JsonValue.Object` are returned, or a `new JsonObject` if `JsonValue.Object` is null. Same goes for `JsonArray`: `JsonValue.Array` ?? `new JsonArray`. Other requested types returns null;

The serializer must be registered with the `SerializerFactory.AddSerializer(mySerializer)` somewhere. For me it is typically in `Global.asax.cs` and in a MSTest `[AssemblyInitialize()]` method.

Here is my implementation at this point:

```cs
public class JsonValueSerializer : ISerializer
{
    public bool ShouldMaintainReferences => false;

    private Type[] HandledTypes = {
        typeof(JsonValue),
        typeof(JsonObject),
        typeof(JsonArray)
    };

    public bool Handles(SerializationContextBase context)
    {
        return HandledTypes.Contains(context.InferredType);
    }

    public JsonValue Serialize(SerializationContext context)
    {
        if (context.Source is JsonValue jsonValue)
            return jsonValue;
        else if (context.Source is JsonObject jsonObject)
            return new JsonValue(jsonObject);
        else if (context.Source is JsonArray jsonArray)
            return new JsonValue(jsonArray);
        else
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }

    public object Deserialize(DeserializationContext context)
    {
        if (context.RequestedType == typeof(JsonValue))
        {
            return context.LocalValue;
        }
        else if (context.RequestedType == typeof(JsonObject))
        {
            return context.LocalValue.Object ?? new JsonObject();
        }
        else if (context.RequestedType == typeof(JsonArray))
        {
            return context.LocalValue.Array ?? new JsonArray();
        }
        return null!;
    }
}
```

**Weakness of this implementation:**
Deserialization can be done with `serializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(myJsonValue)`. A problem with this implementation, is that when I have a complex class with an object property, and that property contains a `JsonObject` (or a `JsonArray`), it works to serialize the complex type into `JsonValue`, but upon deserialization, the previous `JsonObject` would be deserialized into a `JsonValue` of `JsonValueType.Object`. This is different from the original `JsonObject`, since `JsonValue` can contain a `JsonObject`, but `JsonObject` is a type in its own right.

Without additional mechanisms, it would be impossible to know if the `JsonValue` should be kept or if it should be turned back into a `JsonObject` or a `JsonArray`. One could decide that on deserialization, all `JsonValue.Object` would be constantly set to a `JsonObject` type, but that would be wrong when it initially was a `JsonValue` of `JsonValueType.Object` (same for `JsonArray`). Another approach could maybe be to let `JsonObject` get a `"$type"` parameter with the information, but that wouldn't work with `JsonArray`. I have no fix for this behaviour.